# If $H$ and $K$ are cyclic subgroup of $G$ then $HK$ is subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

If $H=\langle a \rangle$ and $K=\langle b \rangle$ are cyclic subgroup of $G$ then $HK = \{ a^ib^j \; | \; 0 \leq i,j \leq p-1 \}$ is subgroup of $G$, given that the $|H| = |K| = p$ where $p$ is prime.

Proof: It’s clear that $e \in HK$
Now we have to show that set is closed . But I am not able to prove that since $G$ is not Abelian group.
Since if G is Abelian then $(a^i \cdot b^j) \cdot (a^p \cdot b^q)=a^{i+p} \cdot b^{j+q}$.
I also have a feeling that it’s not subgroup but I can’t think of any counter example.

Comment: $G=A_5$, $H=\langle (123)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (12345)\rangle$. Note that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $15$.

Comment: @HongyiHuang note the condition that $|H| = |K| =p$

Comment: The order of $H$ and $K$ is same.

Comment: @AdeshSharma My bad. But I think you should add this in the title.

Comment: @i can’t because of word limit.

Comment: Also $G=A_4$, $H=\langle (123)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (134)\rangle$. In this case $|HK|=9$ but $G$ certainly has no subgroup of order $9$.

Comment: @Subhajit We always have $HH=H$ if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @HongyiHuang yes

Comment: @Subhajit If H is subgroup of $Z_4$ Of order 2 then H={0,2} And H+H={0,2} right ? Then I think something wrong with your example.

Comment: @HongyiHuang why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest counterexample is $S_3$. The product of cyclic subgroups generated by $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ resp. is not a subgroup.

Answer (score 5):

First note that $|HK|=\frac{|H|\cdot|K|}{|H\cap K|}$. Since $|H|=|K|=p$, $H\cap K\ne 1$ if and only if $H=K$, in which case $HK=H$ is certainly a subgroup of $G$.

Now if $H\cap K=1$ (which means $H\ne K$), then $|HK|=p^2$. It is well-known that a group of order $p^2$ is abelian. So if $x,y$ are elements of order $p$ in $G$ and $x,y$ are not commutative, then $H=\langle x\rangle$ and $K=\langle y\rangle$ is certainly a counterexample.

There are a lot of such examples for $(G,x,y)$: such as $(S_3,(12),(13))$, $(A_4,(123),(134))$ and so on.